# sbt cross configuration dependencies

Tags: sbt, stack-overflow

what is the reason SBT won't allow me to have dependencies between different configurations of different projects in a multi-project build?

consider the following setup in the main `build.sbt` file:

```scala
lazy val domain: Project = project in file("domain") dependsOn(testUtils % "test->test")

lazy val testUtils: Project = project in file("testUtils") dependsOn(domain % "compile->test")

...
```

I would want to write all my test helpers in `testUtils`, and have each of the other projects' test code to be clean test logic without the (sometimes duplicated among different projects) boilerplate of the aiding methods.

SBT is forcing me to put the `: Project` type, since it complains the value is "recursive". and upon reloading, I get:

```
    ...
    at $281429c805669a7befa4$.domain(build.sbt:142)
    at $281429c805669a7befa4$.testUtils$lzycompute(build.sbt:144)
    at $281429c805669a7befa4$.testUtils(build.sbt:144)
    at $281429c805669a7befa4$.domain$lzycompute(build.sbt:142)
    at $281429c805669a7befa4$.domain(build.sbt:142)
[error] java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

is there a way around this? or should I write test-related logic in each module test, even at the cost of getting the code less organize, many `"test->test"` dependencies, etc'...